# XIB view not showing with correct layout [iOS Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, xib

I'm trying to make a custom alert view and facing some issues with the fact that the displayed view is cutting the bottom half of the view (Images below)

**How it's being displayed:**

[image: How it's being displayed]

**Desired Output:**

[image: Desired output]

So basically, I have a XIB called CustomAlertView supported by a class of same name with init as follows:

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

private func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomAlertView", owner: self, options: nil)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    addSubview(contentView)
    //contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

}
```

I have another class that is responsible for creating an alert, CustomAlert, using the customAlertView. This CustomAlert class is creating the **backgroundView** and **dialogView**( which I'm trying to add my customAlertView to it) with the following code:

```
func initialize(title:String, description:String){
    dialogView.clipsToBounds = true

    backgroundView.frame = frame
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    backgroundView.alpha = 0.6
    backgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTappedOnBackgroundView)))
    addSubview(backgroundView)

    dialogView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    dialogView.frame.size = CGSize(width: frame.width-32, height: frame.height/3)

    dialogView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    dialogView.layer.cornerRadius = 6

    let alertView = CustomAlertView.init(frame: self.bounds)
    alertView.titleLabel.text = title
    alertView.descriptionLabel.text = description
    alertView.cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown

    dialogView.addSubview(alertView)


    addSubview(dialogView)
}
```

I believe that I'm making a confusion with the frames and bounds but couldn't find a solution.

I'd like the desired output to be placed perfectly inside the dialogView.

EDIT

Code for my .show function in CustomAlert

```
func show(animated:Bool){

    self.backgroundView.alpha = 0
    self.dialogView.center = CGPoint(x: self.center.x, y: self.frame.height + self.dialogView.frame.height/2)
    UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(self)
    if animated {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, animations: {
            self.backgroundView.alpha = 0.66
        })
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: 0), animations: {
            self.dialogView.center  = self.center
        }, completion: { (completed) in

        })
    }else{
        self.backgroundView.alpha = 0.66
        self.dialogView.center  = self.center
    }
}
```

Github link [git-alert-view](https://github.com/raphahenrique/poc-alertview-ios)

Comment: Why are you not using autolayouts to add the alert in the view controller?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by use the auto layouts in the view controller. In my view controller I just create the alert passing the title and description, along with a .show (which sets the dialogView to center)

Comment: Can you please add the code of your show() method?

Comment: In your initialize method you are not initializing the CustomAlertView with like you show in the first code block. I think you should load it via nib.

Comment: I edited the first block code, I think is more clear now, sorry the confusion.... I actually loaded the nib in the init

Comment: what is contentView in your commonInit method? Is it the custom alert that you are initializing in first line with xib?

Comment: Yes, it is the entire view in the xib (@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing the same difficulties as me, I was able to accomplish the wanted result.

I used AutoLayouts as suggested by @HAK. But instead of writing my own `NSLayoutConstraint` I used roberthein library called [TinyConstraints](https://github.com/roberthein/TinyConstraints).

Basically, I used as follow:

Instead of

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
alertView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor, constant: 0),
alertView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
alertView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
alertView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor, constant: 
0)])
```

with TinyConstraints:

```
alertView.edges(to: superview)
```

That´s it

Answer (score 0):

Change your CustomAlertView like this:

```
class CustomAlertView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var confirmButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    static func customAlert() -> CustomAlertView {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomAlertView", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! CustomAlertView
    }

}
```

Your CustomAlert's initialize method like this:

```
func initialize(title:String, description:String){
    dialogView.clipsToBounds = true

    backgroundView.frame = frame
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    backgroundView.alpha = 0.6
    backgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTappedOnBackgroundView)))
    addSubview(backgroundView)

    dialogView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    dialogView.frame.size = CGSize(width: frame.width-32, height: frame.height/3)

    dialogView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    dialogView.layer.cornerRadius = 6

    let alertView = CustomAlertView.customAlert()
    alertView.titleLabel.text = title
    alertView.descriptionLabel.text = description
    alertView.cancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown


    dialogView.addSubview(alertView)

    addSubview(dialogView)

}
```

In the CustomAlertView xib:
1. Select fileowner and remove the class (default to NSObject).
2. Select fileowner and then remove all the outlets.
3. Select your content view and give it class = CustomAlertView.
4. Select your CustomAlertView and make all outlet connections.

Final Xib:
[image]

And you have a working alert:
[image]

**PS: Adjust the UI accordingly.**

Comment: Didn't work either, I've attached the github link, to be easier to look at the code

Comment: @RaphaelHenrique Created the pull request in your repo. You can get the code from there.

Comment: Thanks @HAK , the problem with this approach is that I'm stuck with the height and width of my xib file, it has to be a certain size. 
I'm looking for a solution where independently of the size of my xib file, it fills all the dialog view ( with the buttons at bottom part, description at the middle, etc)

Comment: For that you need to use autolayouts.

Comment: How to use autolayouts in this case ? In xib everything is responsive

Answer (score 0):

In your xib class add this :

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    xibSetup()}

func xibSetup() {
    guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
    contentView = view
}
```

Reference from this : https://medium.com/zenchef-tech-and-product/how-to-visualize-reusable-xibs-in-storyboards-using-ibdesignable-c0488c7f525d#.3c0javomy**